# Links hyperref cleveref highlight full on hovering

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, links

**My hyper setup:**

```
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={},
  pdfauthor={},
  pdfkeywords={},
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  bookmarksopen=false,
  bookmarksopenlevel=1,
  colorlinks=true,
  breaklinks,
  linktoc=section,
  linkcolor=darkred,
  linkbordercolor=white,
  citecolor=darkred,
  urlcolor=darkblue,
  pdfborder = {0 0 1},
  pdfview={XYZ null 0 null}
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @murray, highlight the other part, you see that the link is split into two lines, one part of it on the next line. **How to ensure full mouse hover highlight?**

Comment: Please provide a MWE showing the actual source! (Your `hypersetup` command hardly provides the output you show!)

Comment: @murray, what do you mean?

Comment: @Aix Blaine: Please provide a *complete* (but minimal) *working example* of a source `*.tex` document, including a `\documentclass` assertion, loading of needed packages, and any macro definitions, etc, that are used to produce the output you. Without such a source, it is impossible for others to try to diagnose the problem.